# Como Mostrar datos de una tabla relacionada en laravel por id

Tags: laravel

**Estoy realizando un blog con laravel, en donde hay publicaciones y hay comentarios, las publicaciones y comentarios los almacena bien en la base de datos, el problema es que cuando trato de ver una publicación, me trae todos los comentarios de muchas publicaciones almacenadas en la tabla, lo cual solo quiero que muestre los comentarios que están designados solo para esa publicación, alguno me puede ayudar con mi problema o darme indicaciones de cómo solucionar el problema, muchas gracias**

**controlador de Publicacion**

```
public function show(Publicacion $publicacion, Comentarios $comentarios)
{
    //
    // $comentarios = Comentario::doesntHave('id')->get();
    $like = ( auth()->user() ) ?  auth()->user()->meGusta->contains($publicacion->id) : false; 

    // Pasa la cantidad de likes a la vista
    $likes = $publicacion->likes->count();

    
   $data = Comentarios::with('coment')->get();
   
    
    
    
    return view('publicaciones.show', compact('publicacion', 'like', 'likes', 'data'));
}
```

**Controlador para crear los Comentarios**

```
public function store(Request $request, Publicacion $publicacion)
{
    //
    
    //ya funciona solo con php
    $public = auth()->user()->coments()->create([
        'mensaje' => $request['comentario'],
        'publicacion_id' => $request['publicacion_id'],
    ]);
    return view('comentarios.show');

}
```

**relaciones Polimorficas**

```
public function coments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comentarios');
}
```

**Publicacion**

```
//relacion uno a muchos polimorfica
public function coment(){
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Comentarios', 'coment');
}
```

**comentarios**

```
//Relacion polimorfica
public function Coment()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**imagen del error muestra el id de publicacion pero todos los datos de la tabla, comentarios que tiene la relación**
[image: error en publicación]

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que el problema es que en la relación que creaste en la publicación haces referencia a un relación `"comment"` cuando en Comentarios tienes definido `"Comment"`

Comment: No  bro, no me funciono, ya cambie la referencia de las relaciones pero aun nada, me sigue dando los mismos datos, no se cual otro método usar para solucionar ese problema